# Word wrap in mobile version

Tags: html, css, mobile, model-view-controller

I have a two fields, the First and Last name fields which together can hold up to 150 characters, I need to wrap the text in mobile version.

I have done this in the normal desktop version using a CSS class with the below properties

**word-wrap:break-word;**

**word-break:break-all;**

But on the mobile version it still doesn't work and looks like this

[image]

How can I fix this?

Html Code :-

```
<div class="block-unit-confirmation">
    <span>Name:</span><div class="data-field wordwrap wordwrapspace" >@accountholdersname</div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS

```
  .block-unit-confirmation {
      display:block;
      span {
        float:left;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the full code that's being applied. And can you explain the screenshot? Looks like the last word on the first line is breaking one character beyond the vertical black line? And what's the blue stripe from?

Comment: @henry, I have edited the question to include  html

Comment: To start with: those nested styles are LESS not CSS. You'll need to compile them to CSS or the nested `span` styles won't get applied. Guessing the LESS isn't being compiled to CSS because the nested `span {float: left}` rule isn't being applied. ("Name:" would be on the same line as the name). Is it possible this accounts for the whole trouble?